# Bash script backup program

Tags: bash

I've started bash scripting recently and currently I'm working on a program that simplifies backuping using `rsync` . I'd appreciate any feedback on what I've done wrong / what can be improved.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Copyright (C) 2020 ##########, e-mail: ##################

# saver comes with NO WARRANTY. This program is completely free and you can
# redistribute it under the GNU General Public License conditions.
# See https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-3.0.txt for more information

# saver was made to simplify the process of backuping using rsync.

# version 2.2-1

if [[ ! $(id -u) == 0 ]]; then # making sure the progream is executed as root
    exec sudo $0 "$@"
fi

for ((i=1; i=i; i++));  do # here input variables of the script are read one by another using the for loop
    [[ -z ${!i} ]] && break
    case ${!i} in
        \-*) # this is where all the '-' options are
            case ${!i} in
                *s*) option=$option"sync" ;;&  
                *d*) rsyncoptions+=(-n) ;;& 
                *r*) rsyncoptions+=(--delete) ;;&
                *p*) rsyncoptions+=(--progress) ;;&
                *v*) rsyncoptions+=(-v) ;;&
                *h*) option=$option"help" ;;&
                *i*) option=$option"diskinfo" ;;
            esac
        ;;

        *) # here the paths and disks are set
            if [[ -b ${!i} ]]; then
                if [[ -z $sp ]]; then
                    sdp="${!i}"
                else
                    tdp="${!i}"
                fi
            else
                if [[ -b /dev/${!i} ]]; then
                    if [[ -z $sp ]]; then
                        sdp="/dev/${!i}" # sdp = sync disk path
                    else
                        tdp="/dev/${!i}" # tdp = target disk path
                    fi
                else
                    if [[ ${!i} == /* ]]; then    
                        if [[ -z $sp ]]; then
                            sp="${!i}" # sp = sync path
                        else
                            tp="${!i}" # tp = target path
                        fi
                    fi
                fi
            fi
        ;;
    esac
done

case $option in
    sync) # the -s option
        if [[ ! -e $sp ]]; then # checking if the path to sync from exists
            echo -e "The path to copy wasn't provided or doesn't exist\nType in 'saver -h' to see the list of commands"
            logger "saver: The path to copy wasn't provided or doesn't exist"
            exit
        fi

        if [[ -z $tp ]]; then # checking if the target path isn't empty
            echo -e "The target path wasn't provided\nType in 'saver -h' to see the list of commands"
            logger "saver: The target path wasn't provided"
            exit
        fi

        fsp=$sp # these stand for the final paths that will be put to the rsync command (final sync path / final target path)
        ftp=$tp

        if [[ $sdp ]]; then 
            echo "Unmounting the disk to copy"
            umount -q $sdp # mounting the sync external disk to a folder that's made
            
            echo "Creating /mnt/saverbd"
            mkdir /mnt/saverbd | grep -q a
            
            echo -e "Mounting the disk to copy to /mnt/saverbd\n"
            mount $sdp /mnt/saverbd 
            
            fsp=/mnt/saverbd${sp} # updates the final path if it's from an external disk
        fi

        if [[ $tdp ]]; then
            echo "Unmounting the target disk"
            umount -q $tdp # mounting the target external disk to a folder that's made

            echo "Creating /mnt/savertd"
            mkdir /mnt/savertd | grep -q a

            echo -e "Mounting the target disk to /mnt/savertd\n"
            mount $tdp /mnt/savertd

            ftp=/mnt/savertd${tp} # updates the final path if it's from an external disk
        fi

        if [[ ! -e $tp ]]; then
            echo "Creating ${ftp}"
            mkdir -p $ftp | grep -q a 
        fi

        echo

        rsync -aAX "${rsyncoptions[@]}" $fsp --exclude={"/dev/*","/proc/*","/sys/*","/tmp/*","/run/*","/mnt/*","/media/*","/lost+found"} $ftp

        if [[ $sdp ]]; then # unmounting the sync external disk and deleting the mount folder
            echo -e "\nUnmounting the copied disk"
            umount -q $sdp

            echo -e "Deleting /mnt/saverbd\n"
            rm -rf /mnt/saverbd
        fi

        if [[ $tdp ]]; then # unmounting the target external disk and deleting the mount folder
            echo -e "\nUnmounting the target disk"
            umount -q $tdp
            
            echo -e "Deleting /mnt/savertd\n"
            rm -rf /mnt/savertd 
            
        fi
    ;;

    diskinfo)
        lsblk -o NAME,SIZE,MOUNTPOINT,FSTYPE # shows the available disks and partitions
    ;;

    help) # the help page
        echo -e "\n Copyright (C) 2020 ###########, e-mail: ##################
 Version 2.2-1
\n saver comes with NO WARRANTY. This program is completely free and you\n can redistribute it under the GNU General Public License conditions.\n See https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-3.0.txt for more information
\n saver was made to simplify the process of backuping using rsync.
\n This program will automaticly exclude these directories from syncing:\n /dev ; /proc ; /sys ; /tmp ; /run ; /mnt ; /media ; /lost+found.
 When typing in the disk name, you can use the full '/dev/(disk)' or just\n provide the name of the disk.
 Any disk you mention will be unmounted at the end of the program.
\n Usage:
\n -s [disk to copy (empty for current disk)] [copied path]\n    [target disk (empty for current disk)] [target path]
\n Options:
\n -s     Sync folders
 -r     Delete any other files in the target folder
 -d     Preform a 'dry run', no changes will be made
 -p     Display progress for individual files (useful for large files)
 -v     Display files that are being processed
 -i     Show available disks/partitions
 -h     Show this help\n"
    ;;

    *) # in case no valid option is provided
        echo -e "Invalid option provided\nType in 'saver -h' to see the list of commands"
        logger saver: "Invalid option provided" 
    ;;
esac
```

Comment: It does, what I mean by that is if the code I've written can be somehow optimized, if there can be any compatibility issues. I'm new to bash scripting so I tend to make mistakes.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review. To increase the odds of receiving answers about your script, it could be better to modify the title of you post to include a brief description of the task implemented by the script.

Comment: As @dariosicily indicated a better title might be `bash backup script`.

Comment: I changed the title, but "bash backup script" was taken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## loop

```
for ((i=1; i=i; i++));  do 
    [[ -z ${!i} ]] && break
```

you know that `$#` hold number of argument from command line ?

you can use

```
for ((i=1; i <= $# ; i++))
```

## test

```
if [[ ! $(id -u) == 0 ]]
```

you know  about `!=` ? use

```
if [[ $(id -u) != 0 ]]
```

## mkdir

what is the purpose of .. ?

```
mkdir /mnt/savertd | grep -q a
```

Do you want to get rid of `"mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/mnt/savertd’: File exists"` message ?

this won't work (message is printed on stderr, while `|` will collect stdout), use either

```
test -d /mnt/savertd || mkdir /mnt/savertd
```

or

```
mkdir -p /mnt/savertd
```

- second form is better, it will create all directory along the path, first one will fail if `/mnt` do not exists.
- `mkdir -p` will also not complain if directory exists.

## echo -e

you have some

```
echo -e "Mounting the target disk to /mnt/savertd\n"
```

<s>why use both `-e` (no new line) and a trailling `\n` (new line) ?</s>

actually :

- `-e`     enable interpretation of backslash escapes

long `echo -e` in help section can be replaced by a here documentation

```
cat <<EOF
 Copyright (C) 2020 ###########, e-mail: ##################
 Version 2.2-1

 saver comes with NO WARRANTY. This program is completely free and you
 can redistribute it under the GNU General Public License conditions.
 See https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-3.0.txt for more information
 saver was made to simplify the process of backuping using rsync.
 This program will automaticly exclude these directories from syncing:
   /dev ; /proc ; /sys ; /tmp ; /run ; /mnt ; /media ; /lost+found.
 When typing in the disk name, you can use the full '/dev/(disk)' or just provide the name of the disk.
 Any disk you mention will be unmounted at the end of the program.

 Usage:
 -s [disk to copy (empty for current disk)] [copied path]
    [target disk (empty for current disk)] [target path]
 Options:
 -s     Sync folders
 -r     Delete any other files in the target folder
 -d     Preform a 'dry run', no changes will be made
 -p     Display progress for individual files (useful for large files)
 -v     Display files that are being processed
 -i     Show available disks/partitions
 -h     Show this help
EOF
```

Comment: Thanks a lot I've heard about $#, but after I wrote that code so I haven't thought about that. All the other tips are really helpful too. I also wasn't sure how to use a here document, so I used a long echo, but this is much cleaner. Thanks again.

Comment: I'm not sure about what you said of `echo -e` with `\n` . `echo -e` doesn't block a new line. `echo -n` does that. I used 'echo -e' with '\n' to have two new lines.

Comment: yes my fault, `-e     enable interpretation of backslash escapes`